# Using a specific class when there is a namespace ambiguity

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a class called `Message`. It is located inside `MyProgram` namespace. The problem is that `System.Windows.Forms` has also a `Message` class, so whenever I want to use classes from both of the namespaces, I need to write `MyProgram.Message` to refer to my class, which is very tedious.

I hoped this line could work:

```
using static Message = MyProgram.Message;
```

but I get the following error:

> a 'using static' directive cannot be used to declare an alias

Is there a way to force the code to recognize `Message` as `MyProgram.Message`? Also, changing my class's name is not a real solution. :P

Comment: Further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Comment: Put the code into MyProgram namespace so it defaults to the current namespace.   The issue is you are in a different namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`using static` is for static members, not nested types.

A regular `using` directive will work fine.

```
using Message = MyProgram.Message;
```

Comment: Yes. `using static MyType;` means that you can skip `MyType` when accessing a `static` member on that type, so you can write just `SomeStaticMember` instead of `MyType.SomeStaticMember`. Since `MyType` goes away entirely, it does not make sense to give an alias there. For that you use a `using` directive (not "statement") without the `static` keyword. Your solution above still depends on the placement of the `using` directives. If `using System.Windows.Forms;` was inside some `namespace`, while your `using Message = MyProgram.Message;` was outside, the former, "nearer" directive might be used.